# Removing heading, leading, and repeated whitespace but do not remove whitespace in lex and bison

Tags: parsing, bison, flex-lexer, lexical-analysis

I am currently working on a preprocessor of some sort and am using lex and bison to create the lexer and parser part.

And my current implementation has a problem handling whitespace. My first solution was to create a flex rule that ignores whitespace using `[ \t]+ /* do nothing */` this solves some problems wherein it removes all whitespace but it also removes whitespace between keywords so `boxdown` is the same as `box down` wherein it should not be.

My next solution is to return a whitespace token but it doesn't support leading and trailing whitespace and now I need to modify all my bison rules to match for where it needs whitespace and also for some parts where it is optional for example mathematical expressions.

Is there a more standard and tidier way to accomplish this as most of the example I found online doesn't use a dedicated token for whitespace?

Here are the rules of my lexer:

```
"down" { strcpy(yylval.s, yytext); return DIR; }
"box"  { strcpy(yylval.s, yytext); return PRIM; }
\n     { return EOL; }
[ \t]+ { return WS; }
.      { ECHO; }
```

and here is a snippet of the parser:

```
%token <s> PRIM DIR
%token EOL WS

program: statement
       | program EOL statement
;

statement: prim_stmt
;

primt_stmt: PRIM { foo($1, ""); }
          | PRIM WS DIR { foo($1, $3); }
;
```

EDIT:
I have managed to make it allow for trailing and leading whitespaces by adding these 2 lexer rules.

```
^[ \t]+   /* do nothing */
[ \t]+/\n /* do nothing */
```

but I still need to manually change all bison rules to accommodate for the `WS` token

Comment: There isn't enough information here. Some actual code would be useful. If I had to guess, I'd say that you are passing the text through the same lexer twice, which isn't going to work. The output of a C-style preprocessor is not a stream of characters; it's a stream of tokens. Macros are not character strings. They are token vectors. So the only thing you need to pass through lexical analysis after preprocessing is a token created through token concatenation (`##`). In C, pp-tokens are converted to language tokens,  (or at least some are) but that's done one-to-one on individual tokens.

Comment: @rici I am sorry but probably using the `else if` example probably confused you that I am trying to create a C preprocessor which I just used because using C-like tokens would probably make it easier for others to understand. Well, I tried adding some snippets so hopefully, it helps.

Comment: Ok. But nothing in your code shows the problem. There's no need to return the WS token to the parser. So maybe it has to do with the preprocessor (which you don't show) or maybe something else.

Comment: Perhaps this whole preprocessor thing is a distraction. If you want `boxdown` to be a single token --even if just to report an error-- you need a rule which matches it. But it's really not fair to force readers to guess what your problem is. Provide a [mre] with a clear problem description: what (precisely) you did; the (precise) result; and the (precise) desired result.